# ModRewrite Yii Framework

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, yii

I am trying to setup Yii Framework within a subdirectory.

I'm tryint to setup the htaccess rule found here.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url
Or seen below.

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I am adding Yii to a plain old php application. So I'm adding yii as a subdirectory.

so the URI would typically be /yii.

However, it also needs to be able to go another subdirectory, because clients may decide to install the application itself as a subdirectory. So the rewrite rule will also have to work for /app/yii

Answer (score 0):

The htaccess you provided works for all directories. Simply open the url `/yii` or `/app/yii` and it should work.